# What exactly are masques and bergamasques?

Tags: poetry, meaning, french-language, paul-verlaine

In Verlaines's ["Claire de Lune"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clair_de_Lune_(poem)) he speaks of:

> Que vont charmant masques et bergamasques

They play musical instruments, so one assumes them to be musical artists, but what exactly are masques and bergamasques?

Comment: I'm just struggling to find a definition of what a bergamasque is.

Answer (score 8):

The line is a bit of a pun. A "[masque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masque)" is a masked ball, and in this case refers to the kind of music played at masques. The name actually has a somewhat convoluted history, originally referring to a masked drama in France, then to a stylized dance in Elizabethan England, and that use re-exported back to France.

Despite the name a "bergamasque" is not a kind of masque. The name comes from Bergamo, a city in Italy. It refers to the kind of music there, based on a folk dance. That dance is thus Bergamo-esque (bergamasco in Italian, and bergamasque in French, giving rise to [Bergamask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bergamask) in English).

So "masques and bergamasques" puts together two styles of dance and music, both of which have Renaissance origins, even though the names are not actually related.

Comment: And a couple of lines later you have *"sous leurs déguisements fantasques"—"under their fantastic disguises"*—so the word *"masque"* also carries the meaning of *"somebody wearing a mask."*